# how to send 100names in single request in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

How to send list of username like 100 in the single request?

And get the response and its a search request  for above

Is it possible in elasticsearch?

Comment: What do you mean "send"? Indexing or search request?

Comment: its a Search request

Comment: Please update the question including this information as well.

Answer (score 1):

One example for a search request with multiple "terms" to search is `terms` query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "username" : ["john", "mike", "secret"]}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) in Elastic Search.

```
curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/users/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@users.json"
```

users.json file look like below.

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"author":"Author1","id":1}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"author":"Author2","id":2}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"author":"Author3","id":3}
```